# How to hide < in backButton

Tags: ios, navigationbar

I create custom back button in a code by this method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    super.prepareForSegue(segue, sender: sender)
    var barBack = UIBarButtonItem(title: nil, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: nil, action: nil)
    barBack.image = UIImage(named: "btnBack")
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = barBack
}
```

When I opened it looks like this - http://prntscr.com/5st2tk

How can I remove this "<"?

**Update**

Thank you for comments. At end I did next:

```
var barBack = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: nil, action: nil)
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = barBack
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "btnBack")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = UIImage(named: "btnBack")?.imageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal)
```

Comment: Probably need to set the collection: self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = @[yourBackButton];

Comment: I don't want to change leftBarButtonItem.
I just want to change image of backButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want to change image of backButton.

You *have* changed it.

The chevron is not the image of the back button. It is not a property of the back button at all! It is a feature of the *navigation bar*.

You can get rid of it or customize it (it is the bar's `backIndicatorImage`).

But the easiest solution is: Do not worry about the back button item. Use a left bar button item in the *pushed* view controller, and configure it to go back. By default, if there is a left bar button item, the back button item won't appear.

Comment: OP, this is the correct answer and you should accept it (don't know why you haven't yet), but if you need help with the actual implementation, let me know.